# Alternate Ways of Writing Complex Summations

Tags: soft-question

In my writing, I often have to consider summation formulas where describing the terms of the summation make the equation rather weirdly spaced out. For instance, I am currently considering the formula

$$ \sum_{J_1, \dots, J_n \in \mathcal{B}^d_l(E)} \sum_{K \in \mathcal{B}^{dn}_l(G) \cap \mathcal{B}^{dn}_s(J_1 \times \dots \times J_n)} \prod_{i = 1}^n \mathbf{I}(I_{J_i} = K_i). $$

Are there any alternate ways of writing these kinds of formulae, stylewise, which makes the equation look more pleasant. Something really annoys me about the spacing between the different $\Sigma$'s.

Comment: This is maybe not optimal, but already an improvement:
$$\sum_{\substack{J_i,\ldots,J_n\in\mathcal{B}_l^d(E)\\K\in\mathcal{B}^{dn}_l(G)\cap\mathcal{B}^{dn}_s(J_1\times\cdots\times J_n)}}\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbf{I}(I_{J_i}=K)$$
This question should be moved to TeX.SE though...

Comment: or with $J=(J_1,\dots,J_n)$, 
$$ \sum_{J  \in \mathcal{B}^d_l(E)^n\atop K \in \mathcal{B}^{dn}_l(G) \cap \mathcal{B}^{dn}_s(\prod_i J_i)} \prod_{i = 1}^n\; \mathbf{I}(I_{J_i} = K_i). $$

Comment: You can leave only $K$ and $J$ under the summation signs, and explain their range is a separate line, in a separate sentence, "Where the summation is over $J\in...$ and $K\in...$."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it would be much more appropriate for http://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Yemon, it's not really about TeX, as Alexandre's comment shows.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Fair point. Since I can't undo my vote to close (AFAIK) I'll just leave this acknowledgment here

Comment: Whether or not it's about TeX, it's not about research mathematics (or rather, if it is, then so is every question about TeX that occurs when writing a research paper).

Comment: @YemonChoi, if you click again on 'close', then at the bottom-right of the dialogue window there is an option "Retract Close Vote".

Comment: Thanks, @LSpice